# My Server Side Validation in PHP Comes when the Page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

My Server Side Validation Comes first when the Page is loaded, 
i have tried 
`if(!$_REQUEST){`
   `header(.....);`
`}` 
At the start of my method in the controller, but it seems not working,
can anyone knows the right sol?

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done like this to solve the Issue
`public function funName(){` 
         `// to avoid validation when the page loads`
         `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {`
            `$this->load->view('user/index');`
        `}`

```
     ... //rest of content
```

`}`

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `GET` or `POST` to submit your form data?

If you're using `POST`, you can check the request method:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Validate form data
}
else {
    // Display form
}
```

If you're using `GET` you should check if any of the data you need is set. For example:

```
if(isset($_GET["arg1"]) || isset($_GET["arg2"]) || isset($_GET["arg3"]) || ...) {
    // Validate data
}
else {
    // Display form
}
```

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to choose the correct answer to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can also have an `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` and you can check `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...` (I assume you're using Post; most forms should be Post, but it'll work with Get too). You can easily have multiple forms on the same page, and just check the presence of different submit buttons. I find this a little more elegant for checking whether the form was submitted; afterwards you validate the fields (e.g. whether they were filled out, etc.).